# MySQL: How to SELECT COUNT two field names from originating from field name on the same table

Tags: mysql

**SCENARIO:** I want to make a query that can return two or more fields that came from the same column but different in criteria so that i can count the data.

**SQL:**

```
SELECT
       FROM_UNIXTIME(news_date, '%Y-%m-%d') AS `DATE`,
       COUNT(news_slant=1) AS `Neutral`,
       COUNT(news_slant=2) AS `Positive`,
       COUNT(news_slant=3) AS `Negative`
FROM tbl_news
GROUP BY `news_date`
ORDER BY `news_date`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `case` inside `count` :

```
SELECT
FROM_UNIXTIME(news_date, '%Y-%m-%d') AS `DATE`,
COUNT(case news_slant when 1 then 1 else null end) AS `Neutral`,
COUNT(case news_slant when 2 then 1 else null end) AS `Positive`,
COUNT(case news_slant when 3 then 1 else null end) AS `Negative`
FROM tbl_news
GROUP BY `news_date`
ORDER BY `news_date`
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Case Statement:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(news_date, '%Y-%m-%d') AS `DATE`,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN news_slant=1 THEN 1 ELSE null END) AS Neutral,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN news_slant=2 THEN 1 ELSE null END) AS Positive,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN news_slant=3 THEN 1 ELSE null END) AS Negative ,
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY news_date
ORDER BY news_date
```

Comment: Thanks Bro same as Grisha

Answer (score 0):

You can use a standard `IF` clause.  `COUNT()` will only count non-null values.

```
SELECT 
FROM_UNIXTIME(news_date, '%Y-%m-%d') AS DATE, 
COUNT(IF(news_slant=1,1,NULL)) AS Neutral, 
COUNT(IF(news_slant=2,1,NULL)) AS Positive, 
COUNT(IF(news_slant=3,1,NULL)) AS Negative 
FROM tbl_news 
GROUP BY news_date 
ORDER BY news_date
```

Comment: New style case vs if :)

Comment: `CASE` is better suited a comparison with multiple outcomes.